# Dirs Program Files (x86) and Program Files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am developing on a Windows 2008 R2 Server, 64 bit.
I am developing for SharePoint 2007, 64 bit.

My file structure has these two directories.
I am trying to fix a solution reference in VS2007.
Does it matter where I reference something, are these somewhat duplicate dirs, or how should I consider these two dirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Program Files (x86) directory is for applications that are set to run as 32-bit, while the Program Files directory is for applications set to run as 64-bit, so, yes, they should be considered different.